# An introductory question about .eps and fonts

Tags: fonts, pdf, eps

I was asked to change the .pdf figures of a work into .eps files in such way that no fonts will need to be embedded.

I do not understand the relation between .eps and fonts. Do the .eps figures save automatically texts in the fonts that are described in the style?

For instance. Let's suppose that I have the following .pdf figure:
[image]

If I convert the figure .pdf to .eps trhough https://convertio.co/pt/pdf-eps/ and upload in the .tex file, will the .eps file automatically use only predetermined fonts?

If no, how can I determine the fonts of the figure?

Thank you.

Comment: this is off topic here I think. No idea what some random online convertor will do, but you probably have `pdftops` installed which can embed or not with commandline options such as `-noembt1                       : don't embed Type 1 fonts`

Comment: If this is for an employer, I would strongly suggest not using an online converter, simply because you have no idea what the other end will do with the data. Also knowing *why* fonts shouldn't be embedded (e.g. licencing) may suggest or prohibit certain paths forward.